# Is it possible to have an Android Phone app and a iPhone app share a common settings database located on a server?

Tags: android, iphone

I have an Android app and a Web App that both control a Raspberry Pi. There are quite a few settings. Now I am developing a iPhone app that will do the same thing. Rather than having the user enter the same settings in each app, it would be nice if all apps would connect to the raspberry pi and get the settings located maybe in an xml file. Is this possible? My thought would be the app would ask for a Username and Password when started and then use those credentials to connect to the raspberry pi where it would read the settings from an xml file. Any thoughts on how best to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A JSON file with the user preferences can work.

Answer (score 0):

No, both have many number of differences in term of reading the settings from same file.

You can achieve this rather by defining the different setting in other file and one with common settings.